# unwanted implicit argument resolution in higher order function map

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-order-functions

I'm having issues trying to `map` some methods defined with implicit arguments over an `Option` type.

Let's say I define a custom `class` and a `trait` with the aforementioned methods operating on said `class`

```
class MyClass

trait Processor {

  def stringy(implicit arg: MyClass) = arg.toString

  def lengthy(implicit arg: MyClass) = arg.toString.length

  def inty(implicit arg: MyClass) = arg.toString.map(_.toInt).sum

}
```

Then I create an implementation with some tests

```
object TestProcessing extends Processor {

  //Here everything works fine, the argument is passed explicitly    
  def test() {
    val my = new MyClass

    val res = List(stringy(my), lengthy(my), inty(my))

    println(res.mkString("\n"))
  }

  //Still everything ok, the argument is passed implicitly    
  def testImplicit() {
    implicit val my = new MyClass

    val res = List(stringy, lengthy, inty)

    println(res.mkString("\n"))
  }

  object Mapper {
    //class wrapped in an Option
    val optional = Some(new MyClass)

    //trying to factor out common code
    def optionally[T](processFunction: MyClass => T): Option[T] = optional map processFunction

    //now the specific processing methods that should work on the optional value
    def s: Option[String] = optionally(stringy)
    def l: Option[Int] = optionally(lengthy)
    def i: Option[Int] = optionally(inty)

    /*
     * Here the compiler complains that
     *
     *<console>:40: error: could not find implicit value for parameter arg: MyClass
     *                def s: Option[String] = optionally(stringy)
     *                                                   ^
     *<console>:41: error: could not find implicit value for parameter arg: MyClass
     *                def l: Option[Int] = optionally(lengthy)
     *                                                ^
     *<console>:42: error: could not find implicit value for parameter arg: MyClass
     *                def i: Option[Int] = optionally(inty)
     *                                                ^
     */    
  }


}
```

While `optionally` is conceived to explicitly pass the optional value explicitly to its argument function, the compiler demands an implicit definition when I use it on the actual functions.

I have two possible solutions, neither of which is satisfactiory:

1. passing an implicit argument to `optionally` as in

   `optionally(implicit my => stringy)`
2. avoid defining the argument to the specific functions as `implicit`, as in

   `def stringy(arg: MyClass)`

Each solution defies the goal of achieving both readability and usability.

Is there a third way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that the compiler doesn't seem recognize that you want to partially apply / lift the method to a function here (instead it "thinks" you want to leave out the implicit parameter), so doing that explicitly seems to work:

```
def s: Option[String] = optionally(stringy(_))
def l: Option[Int] = optionally(lengthy(_))
def i: Option[Int] = optionally(inty(_))
```

Comment: nice, does this mean that there's no way to partially apply a method with implicit args? `def f[A](implicit a: A) = a` but no: `val ff = f _`?

Comment: at least not by simply leaving out the argument list, it would seem